# Was Knick knack an actual game?

Tags: etymology

In the nursery rhyme “[This old man](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Old_Man)” played Knick knack on my knee, etc. I always assumed it was just nonsense rhyming. Was it a real thing?

> This old man, he played one, 
>   He played knick-knack on my thumb,
>   With a knick-knack paddywhack, 
>   Give the dog a bone, 
>   This old man came rolling home.

Comment: The question includes a link to the Wikipedia article on the nursery rhyme/song "This Old Man," which (it seems to me) constitutes a show of research. The Wikipedia article delves into the history of the song, but it doesn't have any pertinent information on what "playing knick-knack" means. It seems to me that the prerequisite to include research is now satisfied, and that, accordingly, the question should be reopened.

Comment: http://www.anvari.org/shortjoke/Miscellaneous_Jokes/35082_there-was-a-small-frog-who-needed-a-loan-to-buy-a-new-car.html

Comment: Another possibility: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nick%20nack%20paddy%20wack

Comment: @Davo - Yeah, that was my original impression of the meaning of "nick-nack", from when I was a kid and Eisenhower was president.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by the following [source](http://www.learnarhyme.com/Counting_Rhymes/thisoldman.htm), knickknack may refer to tapping out a rhythm usin a spoon.

> This traditional rhyme was first published in 1906 but almost certainly originates from earlier possibly from the time of the Irish potato famine.
>
> The biggest clue to the meaning lies in the lyrics most particularly 'paddywhack' and to a lesser extent 'knick-knack'.
>
> A knick-knack is a trinket or other trivial object. ***Knick-knack may also refer to the practice of tapping out a rhythm using spoons.***

(www.learnarhyme.com)